# How can I run kinetise(framework) source code in Android studio?

Tags: android

I do one template project from "kinetise"(framework) and downloaded the android source code,
but  not able to run this source code in android studio for editing.the downloaded source code was combining of javascript files also.

https://www.kinetise.com/user/dashboard

Answer (score -1):

In kinetise while build code for Android and iOS both it will provide a template in which there are too much irrelevant code you have to search your required file by your own and done changes accordingly.

You must have to share your error here.

Most common error:

Error:Project :Kinetise declares a dependency from configuration 'compile' to configuration 'default' which is not declared in the descriptor for project :facebook-android-sdk.